# Passing variables in nested functions between scripts

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie to jQuery and am trying to make a variable within a nested function available between scripts. However, I am unsure of how to do so (I am pretty bad at understanding scope). Here is the code (note: I copy-pasted this from jsFiddle, hence some tags are purposefully missing).

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>    
    <button id="btn">click</button>
 <script>
    var x;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", "#btn", function() {
           x = "hello world";
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    alert(x);
</script>    
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting? What isn't working?

Comment: It will alert `undefined` as the `alert()` will get executed before the click event happens

Comment: This isn't scope-related, it's time-related. The `alert` will execute when its encountered, the click handler will set `x` only after the click event.

Comment: I think there needs to be some clarification. If you want the alert to happen on `#btn`'s click event, why didn't you put the alert there? If you don't want the alert to happen then, when do you want it to happen?

Comment: To clarify, I basically need x to be accessible by other scripts. So once the button is clicked, and x is set, I need to be able to use x in other pages etc. The alert in the code is just for example. But I need to manipulate the value set by the button click event in a different page.

Answer (score 1):

for that alert to alert `Hello World` you need to add it inside the click function...
since x is redeclare inside the click event .  and you don't have to seperate your `<script>`.

```
<script>
var x;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#btn", function() {
       x = "hello world";
       alert(x); //alerts hello world
    });
    alert(x); //alerts undefined since x is not set as this is executed before the click event as soon as document is ready
});
alert(x); //alerts undefined since x is not set


</script>
```

Comment: yup!!! thanks update... i guess. its time for me to go for a coffee :)...thanks @smerny

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correctly, in your code `<script>  alert(x);</script>` when you are using alert `x` value is not set.

HTML:

```
<button id="set">set</button>
<button id="get">get</button>
```

JS:

```
var x;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#set", function () {
        x = "hello world";
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#get", function () {
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DzwT7/)